# Implementing an image hosting website using WordPress?

Tags: plugins, buddypress, images, hosting, membership

I am exploring the idea of implementing a (vertical) **image hosting service** on a self-hosted WordPress platform.

I have found several php scripts that can be used for a basic image hosting service and I am trying out one of them - but WordPress is such a great platform, and I am more familiar with it, so I would prefer to use WP if possible.

I have found some relevant plugins for WP (Cincopa, BuddyPress etc.), but when I look at their details, they don't look like they would deliver what they promise.

How could I go about it?
What plugins could I perhaps combine to do this?
Do I need to use BuddyPress?

I would like users to be able to post photos, arrange them in galleries/albums, comment/tag them, complete other custom fields relating to the photos - and, **CRUCIALLY**, be able to ***mark them as public, private or friend.***

More advanced membership handling (including membership levels and payment options) would be desirable. I know there are several membership plugins that I could hopefully bring it or customize.

Many thanks for any advice.

Comment: I would just add that I would host the images on Amazon S3 (I see there are WP plugins for this), for security, performance and scalability.

Comment: is there any way or plugin to host images to another site?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you have a second look into BuddyPress and you'll find that your requirements are matched. The awesomeness of BuddyPress means you can have plugins that extend BudyPress.

For your requirement:

> I would like users to be able to post
>   photos, arrange them in
>   galleries/albums, comment/tag them,
>   complete other custom fields relating
>   to the photos - and, CRUCIALLY, be
>   able to mark them as public, private
>   or friend.

You can use the [BuddyPress Media](http://buddypress.org/community/groups/bp-album/) with the [BuddyPress Privacy Component](http://buddypress.org/community/groups/bp-privacy/) plugins.

> More advanced membership handling
>   (including membership levels and
>   payment options) would be desirable. I
>   know there are several membership
>   plugins that I could hopefully bring
>   it or customize.

You can use the [s2Member](http://buddypress.org/community/groups/s2member/) plugin.

*Disclaimer: I have not used these plugins in combinations and could not guarantee that they'll work out of the box. But with little/some modification you would be able to get it all working.*

Comment: Many thanks for your answer Azizur.
I will look at BuddyPress and its plugins again.
It seems though there is a delay in a stable version that includes album creation, which is essential for my project.

With the membership plugins, I usually run into the problem that they are created with the idea of protecting one's own content from users - not letting users manage the protection or sharing of their *own* content.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to simply use a managed WordPress post somebody like WP engine fix the problem they will happily host all of your images on their content delivery network therefore you are able to set them as you choose private whatever. And you do not have to worry about plug-ins interfering with your website
http://www.wpengine.com